# Openid Connect single sign on external web sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid, saml-2.0, openid-connect

I read about saml and openid connect on the web.

I am trying to implement asp.net mvc project with following requirements.

1. User logins my website.
2. User clicks external site link(ex `trello.com`) and redirected to external site  login page.
3. After sign in a consent screen opens with predefined `scopes.User` approves and return back to my site.
4. Id token and access token are received.

To my knowledge, until now you can proceed with openid connect.

However I can't figure out how I can accomplish following requirement with openid connect.

5. After granting access (previous steps via authorization code flow) whenever user logins my site and clicks external site link, user will be automatically signed on external site. (Like Appdirect and Telstra do)

I know I can implement requirement 5 with SAML but I couldn't find a way to do with openid connect.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially SSO and SSO works like:

- Application A authenticates with IDP X
- Application B authenticates with IDP X

When user goes to B, they are already signed on **with the same IDP** and so they don't see a login screen.

But if user goes to:

- Application C authenticates with IDP Y

they will not get SSO.

Comment: Let me clarify.
Imagine I made agreements with various web sites and they act like OpenID Provider.(Let's say trello.com,mailchimp.com)
I initiated authorization code flow between my app and aforementioned websites.User granted some permissions to my app like reading user contacts  and so on.
I also should implement  the following functionality ;
whenever user logins my app and click let's say trello.com icon,user should be automatically logged into trello.com without needing an active session in trello.com(Requirement 5)

Comment: I think what I am looking for IdP Initiated SSO which openid connect doesn't support.Is it true ?

Comment: Yes - IDP Initiated is only SAML.